# convert screen recoding video chunks blob in to multipart for sending in Api as a multipart

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular8, multipartform-data

I am new in angular 8  please suggest me how to convert screen recorded video chucks or blog in to a multipart  for sending file in API (API accept only multipart) thanks in advance

Comment: are you using MediaRecorder or WebRTC?

Comment: I am using mediaRecorder pleae suggest for this

Answer (score 0):

fileupload.component.ts

```
let chunks=[];
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
   chunks.push(e.data);
}
```

onuploadevent

```
 uploadVideo(){
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type : chunks[0].type });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', blob);
    // post request
 }
```

Comment: i want to convert binary to multipart for sending in API its return binary data